# Re-validate input on radio button selection

Tags: jquery, radio-button, jquery-validate

I currently have a form that I use jquery validation on. The form contains a number of radio buttons ("yes", "no") and each corresponding group of yes/no radio buttons has a description textbox that is required if the user selects "Yes". Like this:
[image]

Here is the method that performs the validation:

```
$.validator.addMethod('conditionalrequired', function (value, element, params) {
    var input = $(params);
    var checked = input.prop('checked');
    if (checked) {
        return value != '' && value != "0";
    }
    return true;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("conditionalrequired", ["boolpropertyname"], function (options) {
options.rules["conditionalrequired"] = "#" + options.params.boolpropertyname + 'Yes';

options.messages["conditionalrequired"] = options.message;
```

});

The validation works well. My only problem is when the validation is triggered and the error message is displayed, selecting the "No" option does not remove the error message (it doesn't prevent the form from being submitted though). What do I need to do to get the effect I'm looking for?

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin by default can already handle `radio` buttons all by itself.  It's very unclear why you've found the need to create a custom method for this.  You'll need to explain, and also **show us the rest of the code required to duplicate the issue**.  Where is your `.validate()` method?  Where is the relevant HTML markup?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The radio button selection is not required. By default, it's always selected one way or the other. The textbox needs to be completed if the yes radio button is selected. There are multiple instances like this on the page. What I was able to do  was loop through and validate the form on the "No" selection being made.

Comment: That's not entirely true.  A form could also be loaded with neither `radio` button selected; so in that case `required` is perfectly reasonable.  However, in your case, the plugin should still be correctly toggling the message automatically since it treats `radio` inputs the same as `checkbox` inputs.  Again, we'll need to see enough code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sorry. When I said "By default" I meant my form specifically. I set the values on the controller. I was able to work out what I was looking for. I apologize if I've confused you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the `change` event of the `radio` input you can call [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) to trigger a validation test, which would toggle the relevant error messages as appropriate.

- Fires when any `radio` input is changed.  Only re-evaluates the one `radio` being changed.

  ```
  $('#myform input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
      $(this).valid();  // <- re-validate this one radio input
  });
  ```
- Fires when any `radio` input is changed.  Re-evaluates all `radio` inputs at once.

  ```
  $('#myform input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
      $('#myform input[type="radio"]').valid();  // <- re-validate every radio input
  });
  ```
- Fires when any `radio` input is changed.  Re-evaluates the entire form at once.

  ```
  $('#myform input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
      $('#myform').valid();  // <- re-validate this entire form
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here's what I did to achieve what I was looking for - on the "No" radio button click event, I call:

```
 var validator = $("form").validate();
 validator.element("#textboxName");
```

This validates the input and removes the validation message. I found this solution in the docs [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element).

Comment: FWIW, [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) does the same with less code:  `$("#textboxName").valid()`

Comment: Wrap it inside a jQuery `.each()` and you can rip through all `radio` elements in three lines.  Otherwise, attach it to the form and do it in one line.  `$('myform').valid()`

Comment: If you post an answer with an example, I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: My mistake, an `.each()` is required for all jQuery Validate methods _except_ for `.valid()`.  Answer posted.